# add MouseEvent.CLICK to starling image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, starling-framework

i have a container have many image with scroll , i add `TouchEvent.TOUCH` as event listener instead of `MouseEvent.CLICK` , because starling doesn't support `MouseEvent` .
the problem is when i navigate between images it will listener to `TouchEvent` while i don't need to this ? is there any solution instead of `TouchEvenet` ?

the code :

```
private function onComplete (event:flash.events.Event):void
    {
        bitmapData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
        var newImage:Image = Image.fromBitmap(Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content));
        newImage.height = 154;
        newImage.width = 180;
        addChild(newImage);
        newImage.addEventListener(starling.events.TouchEvent.TOUCH,image_clickHandler);
    }
    private function image_clickHandler(event:starling.events.TouchEvent):void
    {
        var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(stage);
        if (touch != null)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN)
            {
                //some code
            }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: `TouchEvent` is not instead of `MouseEvent`! The same `TouchEvent` also working in browser like ordinary `MouseEvent`.

Comment: i search and found this [question](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/mouse-events) , for that i write the TouchEvent is instead of MouseEvent

Comment: All right , it's "the same class". did you try the solution with a `stage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good practice not to attach event listeners to **every** objects on scene . You should attach only **one** listener to stage and after that read touch event's `target` property.
Here the example from "Inroducing Starling" book:

```
private function onClick(e:TouchEvent):void
{
 var touches:Vector.<Touch> = e.getTouches(this);
 var clicked:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
 if ( touches.length == 1 )
 {
  var touch:Touch = touches[0];   
  if ( touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED )
  {
   trace ( e.currentTarget, e.target );
  }
 }
}
```

Here , `currentTarget` is `Stage` , and `target` will be your image

Comment: it's work done . Thanks ,, if i don't need to use TouchEvent , is there an event as starling.events.Event.TRIGGERED or MouseEvent.CLICKED ?

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra always welcome, i advice you to use the "Introducing Starling" book as user manual